# How to echo the result of my query? PHP & MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

so I have this query:

```
SELECT COUNT( * ) AS cnt
FROM table
WHERE datetime > NOW( ) - INTERVAL 45
SECOND
```

When I preform this query in MySQL I get the result: `cnt 25` (http://puu.sh/7ZNh.png)

I now want to echo this in my PHP page, how would I do this?

UPDATE:

Here is the full code

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("host","user","pass");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }
mysql_select_db("db", $con);
$query = ("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM usersonline WHERE datetime > NOW() - INTERVAL 5       MINUTE");
$result = mysql_query($query);
?>
```

Comment: there are examples of what you want to do in the php manual, http://nz.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
list($count) = @mysql_fetch_row(mysql_query($sql));

echo $count;
```

Comment: Do NOT use '@' unless you there's a VERY special reason for it. Disable error displaying & enable logging if you must, but you _will_ regret using '@'s while debugging. /hates having to resort to [scream](http://php.net/scream)

Comment: @Wrikken Why not? You can use expression `if($count === false) { // error happened }` instead of messing your code with 3 lines (mysql_query, mysql_num_rows, mysql_fetch_row)

Comment: @Peter: because _any_ error is muted, not just 'expected' ones. Furthermore, a query `SELECT COUNT(*)..` will _always_ return 1 row if the database connection stays up, never more or less. The only moment it doesn't, is when you lose your database connection / the query errors out on a syntax error / something else far more catastrophic happens that you DO want to know.

Comment: Also, just set the appropriate `error_reporting` setting if you do not wish to see these errors, don't abuse `@` for it. Someone else working on your code might actually care about those errors you are suppressing.

Comment: We are talking now about simple query in simple script. If you want to handle MySQL in proper way make your own DB class and use PDO. Eot.

Answer (score 0):

Within your PHP application you need to setup a database object which can be used to connect to your database in order to execute your queries. A good place to start is with PHP PDO, more info @ http://us.php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php along with some good examples.

Answer (score 0):

```
$con = mysql_connect("host","user","pass");
if (!$con)
{
  die('Could not connect: '.mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db("db", $con);
$query = ("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM usersonline 
           WHERE datetime > DATESUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 5 MINUTE) ");
$result = mysql_query($query);
if (!$result) 
{ 
  die('Error in select statement: '.mysql_error()); 
}
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
echo "number of rows = ".htmlentities($row['cnt']);
```

Comment: This will echo "number of rows = " and then nothing, I will update my first post with the full code.

Comment: @user1026128 use `mysql_fetch_assoc` instead of `mysql_fetch_row`

Comment: mysql_fetch_assoc -> $row['cnt'], mysql_fetch_row -> $row[0]. See docs for more information.

Comment: @user1026128 Fixed to the to use fetch_array, now you can use both numbered and named indexes.